# Calculate distance between coordinates in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, haversine

I have two dataframes as follow:

**df_customers.head()**

```
|    | customer_id                      |   zip_code_prefix | coords                                    |
|----+----------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------|
|  0 | 06b8999e2fba1a1fbc88172c00ba8bc7 |             14409 | (-20.509897499999997, -47.3978655)        |
|  1 | 18955e83d337fd6b2def6b18a428ac77 |              9790 | (-23.72685273154166, -46.54574582941039)  |
|  2 | 4e7b3e00288586ebd08712fdd0374a03 |              1151 | (-23.527788191788307, -46.66030962184773) |
|  3 | b2b6027bc5c5109e529d4dc6358b12c3 |              8775 | (-23.49693002789165, -46.185351975305366) |
|  4 | 4f2d8ab171c80ec8364f7c12e35b23ad |             13056 | (-22.98722237101393, -47.151072819246686) |
+----+----------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

**df_sellers.head()**

```
|    | seller_id                        |   zip_code_prefix | coords                                     |
|----+----------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------|
|  0 | 3442f8959a84dea7ee197c632cb2df15 |             13023 | (-22.898536428530225, -47.063125168330544) |
|  1 | d1b65fc7debc3361ea86b5f14c68d2e2 |             13844 | (-22.382941116125448, -46.94664125419024)  |
|  2 | ce3ad9de960102d0677a81f5d0bb7b2d |             20031 | (-22.91064096725142, -43.17650983181368)   |
|  3 | c0f3eea2e14555b6faeea3dd58c1b1c3 |              4195 | (-23.657250175378767, -46.61075944811122)  |
|  4 | 51a04a8a6bdcb23deccc82b0b80742cf |             12914 | (-22.971647510075705, -46.53361841170685)  |
+----+----------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to calculate the difference between those coords columns with [haversine](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/) library without having to merge those dataframes(**There is a Many-to-Many relationship between them**).

So what I am looking for is a way to merge both dataframes on the fly by column **zip_code_prefix** while using the haversine library to calculate coordinates distance in KM.

Is that possible?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand before posting an answer. I have an idea, but I don't know if it's acceptable. You want the distance between each combination of zip codes. Because there are multiple locations in a zip code, you will have to randomly sample points in the zip code to calculate distance. I.e. you can only measure the distance between two points. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I only need the distance between df_sellers['coords'] and df_customers['coords] on a new column( df_customers['distance_from_seller]) .

Forgot to mention that in this particular case there will be always unique locations (coords) for each zip_code_prefix.

Comment: Does every `df_customers` within a zip code have the same `coords`?

Comment: Exactly! , just edited my previous comment.

Comment: One question/comment, I think you'll need a merge at some point. You can reduce the data after the merge, but without a merge, you'd need to do an iterator.

Comment: This is best done with sklearn balltree, let me know if you need an working example. FOr that, I do need copy/pasteable data (json) that can create a dataframe